# Unable to fetch minimum balance for rent exemption while using spl-account-compression

Tags: solana-program

using this for account calculating the rent exemption

```
let space = getConcurrentMerkleTreeAccountSize(24, 64, 21);
let res = connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(space).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

on running getting

```
Unable to fetch minimum balance for rent exemption
```

worked with merkle trees till 20,2048,15

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to setup canopy for a merkle tree using spl\_account\_compression? need to create a merkle tree with >24 nodes](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/how-to-setup-canopy-for-a-merkle-tree-using-spl-account-compression-need-to-cre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid depth pair, but you will run into Solana account size limit issues. The max amount you can store in a Solana account is 10MB. When you have canopy depth set to anything higher than 17 with the maxDepth at 24 and maxDepth 64 - it surpasses the 10485760 (10MB) bytes a Solana account can store.

The config you posted above shows 134270264 bytes are needed (134.27 MB).