# how to setup canopy for a merkle tree using spl_account_compression? need to create a merkle tree with >24 nodes

Tags: solana-program

I am trying to create Merklee tree with >24 nodes, and as I checked the docs, we can setup something like canopy, which I setup to 15 for this use case.
so my
nodes = 24
buffer size = 256
canopy = 15

I got
using this for account calculating the rent exemption

```
let space = getConcurrentMerkleTreeAccountSize(24, 64, 21);
let res = connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(space).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

on running getting

```
Unable to fetch minimum balance for rent exemption
```

worked with merkle trees till 20,2048,15

Comment: What was the value of space for your case that did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a valid depth pair, but you will run into Solana account size limit issues. The max amount you can store in a Solana account is 10MB. When you have canopy depth set to anything higher than 17 with the maxDepth at 24 and maxDepth 64 - it surpasses the 10485760 (10MB) bytes a Solana account can store.

The config you posted above shows 134270264 bytes are needed (134.27 MB).